# How to copy/export part of my SQL database

Tags: sql-server, export, copy, testing

So I have this huge live SQL database. I want to do some testing so I thought to export it, however, it is around 200 GB which is impossible to export.

I thought maybe I export the schema of it and then populate it with random data, but that doesn't seem a good idea and it will take so much time to do so.

Another suggestion is to only export part of it. They challenge is that it's relational database which has 7 tables which are connected to each other and when export like 1000 rows from one table I want to export the related rows in the other tables so I don't encounter errors of missing data while testing. This is the schema of the database.

Any suggestion/hint would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hint: search for "test data management"

Comment: What format are you trying to export to? (CSV/MySQL/Oracle)? Or are you trying to simply export your database to another server?

Comment: Just export to another server .. however, I want just part of the data. Please read the question and the given answer.

Comment: It seems that the given answer has been removed